# Regex With Multiple Condition

Tags: regex

How can i assign multiple condition within a single regex?

For example: i want a string that start and end with characterized words, and it may have space in middle, the length can be 1 too.

So i write this:

```
(?=^[a-zA-Z0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]$)(?=^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$)
```

but this doesn't work.
i though like this:

`(?=^[a-zA-Z0-9])` String start with a to z and 0 to 9

`(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]$)` it also end with the same characters

`(?=^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$)` and it can contain many a to z, 0 to 9 and spaces (which with the above condition, this should be in middle of string)

Comment: Why do you use only lookaheads?

Comment: @RadLexus i'm really don't get use ahad and backward, so ?= is looking after... then what is after? the second condition? or rest of string or ...???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 ]+[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

If string can one character long:

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9]$)[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$
```

Comment: thats 3 cahracter minimum, that's why it cant be simple, so you moved out the begin and end, i tried that too, but i didn't add .*, what that does? and seem i were wrong to put main statement inside third parentheses right?

Comment: @deadManN: The second lookahead asserts there are 0 or more any char before 1 alphanum at the end of the string. You can put the main statement inside a lookahead but there're no needs for that.